# Align minted number of lines inside and outside of a tcolorbox

Tags: luatex, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, minted

I have this MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\setminted{linenos}

\tcbset{
    common/.style={
        before=\vskip2\baselineskip\noindent,
        enhanced,
        title empty,
        frame empty,
        segmentation empty,
        middle=0.7cm,
        top=0.5cm,
        left*=1.5mm, right*=1.5mm, bottom=0pt
    }
}

\DeclareTColorBox{coolbox}{O{}mO{}}{
    common,
    interior code={
        \filldraw[ultra thick,fill=white,draw=black,rounded corners=10pt,#1] (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east)[sharp corners] -- (frame.south east);
        \node at  ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=3pt]interior.north east) {\includegraphics[#3]{#2}};
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{coolbox}{example-image}[width=1.5cm,angle=-20]
    \begin{minted}{bash}
ENV="() { :; }; echo foo" bash
    \end{minted}
\end{coolbox}

\begin{minted}{bash}
ENV="() { :; }; echo foo" bash
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

that produces
[image: output]
using

```bash
latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -synctex=1 -lualatex ./foo.tex
```

But as you can notice there is a problem with number of lines (I highlighted it with the  purple color). In particular the first `minted` environment is inside `coolbox` but the second one not. So the first `minted` is squashed inside `coolbox`.

The question: **Is it possible to avoid the squashing on the left side of `coolbox` (only on the left because it always opens) to align number of lines outside and inside of it?**

Comment: Does setting `left*=0mm` in line 19 give what you want?

Comment: Thank you @Οὖτις! **It works**. If you want add this comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings for `tcolorbox` are responsible for that. In your `\tcbset` command you use `left*=1.5mm` which causes the identation. The tcolorbox documentation for `/tcb/left*=⟨length⟩` reads

> Sets /tcb/left such that ⟨length⟩ is the distance between the left bounding box and the text parts.

In your case it should suffice to set `left*=0mm`.